# yum giving error "[Errno 111]" Connection refused on RHEL

Tags: linux, redhat-enterprise-linux, package-management, yum, rhel-7

I am on RHEL server 7*. When I use yum (any command even help) I get this line every time.

```
 [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Things work, but lines like this keep coming.

Answer (score 0):

if you're behind a proxy, edit `/etc/rhsm/rhsm.conf` to reflect your proxy congratulation

e.g.

```
# an http proxy server to use (enter server FQDN)
proxy_hostname = my.proxy.com 

# port for http proxy server
proxy_port = 3120

# user name for authenticating to an http proxy, if needed
proxy_user = username

# password for basic http proxy auth, if needed
proxy_password = password
```

see /var/log/rhsm/rhsm.log if you want to see what's going on yum commands

ref : https://access.redhat.com/solutions/65300